# OpenGL ray tracing using inverse transformations

Tags: c++, opengl, raytracing

I have a pipeline that uses model, view and projection matrices to render a triangle mesh.

I am trying to implement a ray tracer that will pick out the object I'm clicking on by projecting the ray origin and direction by the inverse of the transformations.

When I just had a model (no view or projection) in the vertex shader I had

```
Vector4f ray_origin = model.inverse() * Vector4f(xworld, yworld, 0, 1);
Vector4f ray_direction = model.inverse() * Vector4f(0, 0, -1, 0);
```

and everything worked perfectly. However, I added a view and projection matrix and then changed the code to be

```
Vector4f ray_origin = model.inverse() * view.inverse() *  projection.inverse() * Vector4f(xworld, yworld, 0, 1);
Vector4f ray_direction = model.inverse() * view.inverse() *  projection.inverse() * Vector4f(0, 0, -1, 0);
```

and nothing is working anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you use perspective projection, then I recommend to define the ray by a point on the near plane and another one on the far plane, in normalized device space. The z coordinate of the near plane is -1 and the z coordinate of the far plane 1. The x and y coordinate have to be the "click" position on the screen in the range [-1, 1] The coordinate of the bottom left is (-1, -1) and the coordinate of the top right is (1, 1). The window or mouse coordinates can be mapped linear to the NDCs x and y coordinates:

```
float x_ndc = 2.0 * mouse_x/window_width - 1.0;
flaot y_ndc = 1.0 - 2.0 * mouse_y/window_height; // flipped

Vector4f p_near_ndc = Vector4f(x_ndc, y_ndc, -1, 1); // z near = -1
Vector4f p_far_ndc  = Vector4f(x_ndc, y_ndc,  1, 1); // z far = 1
```

A point in normalized device space can be transformed to model space by the inverse projection matrix, then the inverse view matrix and finally the inverse model matrix:

```
Vector4f p_near_h = model.inverse() * view.inverse() *  projection.inverse() * p_near_ndc;
Vector4f p_far_h  = model.inverse() * view.inverse() *  projection.inverse() * p_far_ndc;
```

After this the point is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), which can be transformed by a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) to a  [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system):

```
Vector3f p0 = p_near_h.head<3>() / p_near_h.w();
Vector3f p1 = p_far_h.head<3>()  / p_far_h.w();
```

The "ray" in model space, defined by point `r` and a normalized direction `d` finally is:

```
Vector3f r = p0;
Vector3f d = (p1 - p0).normalized()
```

Comment: I'm trying this and still not quite intersecting. It seems to be off by quite a large factor as the ray_origin is all > 1, when previously it was all between 0 and 1.